# Gridlayout - sizing of element over extending past elements

Tags: android, xml, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

## Intro/Issue

I'm using a mobile app called AIDE (and it's program App UI Designer) to create a layout for an mobile app I'm making before I start programming it. The layout is almost perfect. I'd want the playerTwo portion to be on the top of the screen, upside-down for the purpose of both players being able to use it. Then I'd add a divider in the middle, and the playerOne portion would be on the bottom, with the blank space/divider in the middle. The problem is, the divider, when set to Wrap Content for the height, it overextends off the screen going down, pushing the playerOne section off screen.

## What I Need

I need the divider to keep expanding in height until the playerOne portion is on the bottom of the screen and playerTwo section is on the top.

## What I've tried

- Changing the row and column span of every element
- Changing the layout gravity to Center, Fill, Fill Vertical, etc. on various elements
- Modifying the row and column of the divider
- Modifying the gravity, margins, and padding of the divider
- Changing the height to Match Parent

  ## Screenshots

#### Layout with Fixed Height (`10 dp`)

[image: Layout with fixed height]

#### Layout with Wrap Content

[image: Layout with wrap content]

## XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    columnCount="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    rowCount="1"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="8">

    <!-- Start of Player Two Section -->
    <!-- Current LP -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="8000 LP"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:rotation="180"
        android:id="@+id/playerTwo_LP"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"/>
    <!-- Toolkit -->
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="TOOLS"
        android:rotation="180"
        android:id="@+id/playerTwo_toolKit"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"/>
    <!-- Cards Tool -->
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="CARDS"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:rotation="180"
        android:id="@+id/playerTwo_CardLibrary"/>
    <!-- Add LP -->
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="ADD LP"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:rotation="180"
        android:id="@+id/playerTwo_addLP"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"/>
    <!-- Lose LP -->
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="LOSE LP"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:rotation="180"
        android:id="@+id/playerTwo_loseLP"
        android:layout_row="0"/>
    <!-- Player Two Name -->
    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="Seto Kaiba"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/playerTwo_name"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:rotation="180"/>
    <!-- End of Player Two Section -->
    <View
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center|fill"/>
    <!-- Start of Player One Section -->
    <!-- Player One Name -->
    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="Yugi Muto"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/playerOne_name"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:rotation="0"/>
    <!-- Current LP -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="8000 LP"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:rotation="0"
        android:id="@+id/playerOne_LP"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"/>
    <!-- Toolkit -->
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="TOOLS"
        android:rotation="0"
        android:id="@+id/playerOne_toolKit"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <!-- Cards Tool -->
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="CARDS"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:rotation="0"
        android:id="@+id/playerOne_CardLibrary"/>
    <!-- Add LP -->
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="ADD LP"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:id="@+id/playerOne_addLP"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:layout_column="0"/>
    <!-- Lose LP -->
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="LOSE LP"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:id="@+id/playerOne_loseLP"
        android:layout_row="7"/>
    <!-- End of Player One Section -->
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, I think `GridLayout` is the wrong choice for your parent layout. You can tell just by looking at your layout that it's not *really* a grid. Sure, you can use spans to make it work for you, but you'd be better off choosing a parent layout that you didn't have to fight.

I recommend `ConstraintLayout`. It is almost tailor-made for layouts like this one. You can tell it nice things like "put this view in the top-right corner" and "put this other view in the bottom left corner". Or "stretch this view to fill all the space between these two other views".

Here's what your layout would be if you re-wrote it to use `ConstraintLayout`:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <!-- player two section -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/playerTwo_addLP"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ADD LP"
        android:rotation="180"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/playerTwo_toolKit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TOOLS"
        android:rotation="180"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/playerTwo_addLP"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/playerTwo_loseLP"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LOSE LP"
        android:rotation="180"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/playerTwo_CardLibrary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CARDS"
        android:rotation="180"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/playerTwo_loseLP"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/playerTwo_LP"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="8000 LP"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:rotation="180"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/playerTwo_addLP"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/playerTwo_loseLP"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/playerTwo_toolKit"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/playerTwo_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:text="Seto Kaiba"
        android:rotation="180"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/playerTwo_toolKit"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <!-- player one section -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/playerOne_addLP"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ADD LP"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/playerOne_toolKit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TOOLS"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/playerOne_addLP"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/playerOne_loseLP"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LOSE LP"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/playerOne_CardLibrary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CARDS"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/playerOne_loseLP"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/playerOne_LP"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="8000 LP"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/playerOne_toolKit"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/playerOne_toolKit"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/playerOne_CardLibrary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/playerOne_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:text="Yugi Muto"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/playerOne_toolKit"/>

    <!-- divider -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/playerTwo_name"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/playerOne_name"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Its throwing errors over my mobile AIDE saying "aapt: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintTop_toTopOf' in the package 'thegaminghideout.yugioh'. Is it because my mobile aide maybe doesn't support it? The layout itself outputs just the text "android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout"

Comment: I figured it out. AIDE (the app I'm using) didn't have Maven libraries imported by default so I had to manually add that to the build file, and now all those errors are gone. Thanks!

Comment: When I use the AIDE's App UI Designer program on my phone, now it only shows the text `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`. The AIDE installed the Maven libraries, so the layout properly functions as you showed. I'll edit my question to have the screenshot of how it looks; I'm just wondering if it's possible to have it properly show or does the app itself not support it?